# Unresolved attribute reference 'dispatcher' for class 'Updater'

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I try to create a Telegram bot but I can't use property Update class.

```py
import logging
from multiprocessing import Queue

from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler

def main():
    update_queue = Queue()
    updater = Updater("API KEY", use_context=True, update_queue=update_queue)

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Idle say that there is no **dispatcher** in Update class. Try update Telegram api, didn't help. Can't find another way to update bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 20.0 the `Updater` is only used to fetch updates, from the [docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html#telegram.ext.Updater):

> Changed in version 20.0:
>
> - Removed argument and attribute user_sig_handler
> - The only arguments and attributes are now `bot` and `update_queue` **as now the sole purpose of this class is to fetch updates**. The entry point to a PTB application is now [`telegram.ext.Application`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application).

---

So if you want to add a handler, use an [Application](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application).

An example, taken from the [echo bot example](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/examples.echobot.html):

```py
async def echo(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    """Echo the user message."""
    await update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)


def main() -> None:
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Application and pass it your bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token("TOKEN").build()

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    # on non command i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, echo))

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yep it work, thx,  but still have problem with start and buttom `application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

 application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))`       Expected type '(Update, CallbackContext | Any) -> Coroutine' (matched generic type '(Update, CCT) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, RT]'), got '(update: {message}, context: Any) -> None' instead

Comment: This seems out of the current question scope. To keep things clean here I'd suggest asking another question.

Comment: This def for Start `def start(update:Update, context):`

Comment: You're missing the `async` in front of `def` ;)

Comment: Ty alredy finde that out)